# list view Filter between dates

Tags: list, list-view, 2016, filter, view

I have a list where I have 2 date time columns names as start and End date. 
I'm looking to create a list where items can be filtered if they lies within these date ranges of start  and end date.

Can someone please help me with the list view filter that we have in Views through which we can achieve the above output.

I'm using SharePoint 2016 , classic list view for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What SharePoint version? Classic or modern view? Should the date you filter on be a static date or the current date?

Comment: sharepoint 2016, onpremise , classic view..
date should be on the basis of current date

Comment: Are you planning to apply the filter on the same list which has two dates columns?

Comment: @HabiburRahaman : Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try your list view filter something like below:

[image]

Comment: You can change the field names according to your list structure (Use End Date instead of Due Date in example).

Comment: this will not suffice the requirement as if the start date is anything less the value of a, it will show the items . 
What I;m looking for is to filter items between the start date and end date .
I did tried the above scenario though, but it didn't worked

Comment: Use **AND** operator instead of **OR**. Check updated screenshot.

Comment: Thank you soo much, Much appreciated. I was confused with the logic a bit...My bad!
Thank you for the help one again :)